# How to get username from ChangeItem Object

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

can you please tell me, how to retrieve the user who make the change on the ChangeItem object please.

below the code used :

```
var col = oList.GetChanges(cq);
clientContext.Load(col);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Change change in col)
{

if (change is ChangeItem)
{
ChangeItem ci = change as ChangeItem;
ChangeType changeType = ci.ChangeType;
string itemId = ci.ItemId.ToString();

//RETRIEVE THE USER WHO MAKE THE CHANGE

// .................

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
var col = oList.GetChanges(cq);
clientContext.Load(col);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Change change in col)
{

    List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomList");  //change as per list name
    if (change is ChangeItem)
    {
        ChangeItem ci = change as ChangeItem;
        ChangeType changeType = ci.ChangeType;
        string itemId = ci.ItemId.ToString();

        var modifiedBy = ci.Editor;
        var modifiedLoginName = ci.EditorLoginName;                                        

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Gautam and thank you for your help.
I have a question. for example, if i have an event "Change" on the same item but different user, your code will retrieve always the last person who edited the item. no ?

Comment: Glad I could help, could you please mark it as answer if it resolved your problem ?  :)

Comment: Hello Gautam and thank you for your help. I have a question. for example, if i have an event "Change" on the same item but different user, your code will retrieve always the last person who edited the item. no ?

Comment: My bad, sorry, can you check edited code ?

Comment: Hello, Can't retrieve those two properties :
ci.Editor & ci.EditorLoginName. Are they properties of changeItem Object ??

Comment: Yes they are , you need to update the CSOM dll to the latest one. Check this link - https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-september-2016

Comment: Those properties came with the newest CSOM, seems that they are not yet supported even by SP online... I have the same situation here